# Is there documentation for asio that explains the possible error codes and why they would result?

Tags: c++, boost-asio

For example, `asio::async_connect()`, the [documentation](http://think-async.com/Asio/asio-1.10.6/doc/asio/reference/async_connect/overload1.html) doesn't provide the possible error codes that could result.

It does provide a bunch of [`error_codes`](http://think-async.com/Asio/asio-1.10.6/doc/asio/reference/error__basic_errors.html) and a brief explanation, but is doesn't tell me which errors the `async_connect` function could send to the handler. Basically, I want to know if this error is something that can be recovered or not.

I'd rather not have to go through all the errors for every handler to work out whether it can be recovered or not. My reasoning is that sometimes, depending on the situation `error_x` might be recoverable, other times it's not.

Comment: Maybe because the errors map to the actual errors e.g. [`connect`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/connect.2.html) would give you?

Answer (score 0):

What Joachim said holds some truth (although these underlying calls are also not documented within Asio documentation).

There is only a very small set of generic errors like `operation_aborted` that always apply.

You could look at mapping `error_code` to `error_condition` which is more high-level and should reduce the decision domain, if only across different platforms.